# Create your own java application server from scratch

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

Is anyone aware of any tutorial or link from where I could learn how to create my own custom application server like **Tomcat** or **Jboss**.

Comment: I would rather suggest that you contribute to open source application servers.

Comment: Looking for a tutorial on how to implement an application doesn't mean that he is trying to re-invent the wheel. It is much easier to understand how the existing application servers work, if there is at leat a simple tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Here You have [top 6 Java EE application servers](http://soa.dzone.com/articles/top-open-source-javaEE-application-servers). In server site You can find documentation, and source code. It should help you. But BTW why are You trying to do it?

Answer (score 0):

No link that i know of, but you could take a look at Glassfish (a Java EE reference implementation) as it is open source.

Might be a good starting point.